# Invariance of curvature in Curvature Scale Space

Tags: curvature

[Paper is here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~wes/CSSSlides.pdf)

[image]

I have read this paper. But i don't know what the Invariance means in page 3 and 5. Calculation/estimation of κ is NOT invariant and Invariant to viewpoint. What's the meaning of these sayings? When i read "Invariant to viewpoint", i think it means the k value is same when rotation and translation. But after i read "Calculation/estimation of κ is NOT invariant" ,i have no idea. Then i try the code what i got here,to caculate the k value.

[Code is here](https://github.com/royshil/CurveMatching)

And i have found that, the k value is different when shape have rotated which have the same sigma. Then i changed the sigma, k value is also different while the shape is same. When i set the sigma as 0.6667, the curvature of straight line is 1.6 not 0, why? The curvature of straight line should be zero,right? I don't why the value is 1.6. Then I tried to rotate the straight line, the curvature changed!!new value is -6.6. The papge said to find zero crossing to get concave-convex. But here  curvature of straight line is not 0 is 1.6? Can somebody help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: It says it is not invariant to zooming. If you have the earth, zooming in on an ocean it would seem flat on the horizon, zooming out it would look more and more curved as the earth actually is round.

Comment: I don't get what the dots mean. Is it derivative with respect to $s$? So these are parametrized curves?

Comment: @mathreadler Yes,these are parametrized curves.What does zooming mean here?These  are  2d curves.

Comment: Imagine a circle drawn on a piece of paper. If you zoom out it looks like it has a higher curvature. If you zoom in the circle looks almost flat.

Comment: @mathreadler Thank you!got it. But i don't know why the curvature of straight line not be zero, and will change by rotation?